# Android Load Spinner data from Server

Tags: android, android-volley

I am learning android volley library. I am trying to populate data from server to spinner. 
my JSON is:

```
{"data":{"Bangalore":["Painting","Carpentering","Plumbing","Electrical works"],"Hydrabad":["Plumbing"],"kochi":["Painting","Carpentering"]},"status":200}
```

Now I am trying to get only Bangalore, hydrabad, kochi in One Spinner. Upon selecting the City I want to load the work(Painting , Plumbing etc..) in other spinner. I am not able to get the city names in spinner.

My Volley Request Code is:

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jo = response.getJSONObject("data");
                    name=jo.toString();
                    ids.add(name);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, ids));
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
        rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        rq.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Please help me out.. 
Thanks in advance......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to get only Bangalore, hydrabad, kochi in One Spinner

All Bangalore, hydrabad, kochi,... is key in `data` `JSONObject` which contains  `JSONArray` as value.

To show all city name in one `Spinner` first need to get all city names from `data` JSONObject as:

```
JSONObject jo = response.getJSONObject("data");
JSONArray cityNameJSONArray= jo.names();
```

Now use `cityNameJSONArray` JSONArray to show city names in `Spinner`.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply

Comment: @MadhuKumar: got it or getting issue?

Comment: How can I get the work names(Painting, plumbing) upon selecting the city name..@ρяσѕρєя K

Comment: Use a Map where key is name of city and value is ArrayList of worknames then on selecting city name pass it to Map to get all  work names related to city

Comment: I am tried I am not exactly getting output.. Can you Please..... share code for it.... @ρяσѕρєя K